# Windows Service - Erro 1053 ao Iniciar

Tags: c#, windows, services, windows-service

Olá,

Tenho um serviço do windows em C# que tenho que instalar em diversos clientes. O meu problema é que em alguns clientes eu consigo instalar e ele funciona normalmente, porém em alguns clientes eu consigo instalar o serviço mas o mesmo não inicia de jeito nenhum. Eu mal inicio o serviço e ele me da a mensagem

> "Erro 1053: O serviço não pode ser inicializado pois não respondeu a solicitação em tempo hábil"

Se fosse um erro do serviço eu conseguiria ver os logs no **Event Viewer** do windows, mas o problema é que não aparece log algum, o que está me levando a acreditar que o serviço nem está sendo executado e o erro acontece antes do mesmo iniciar.

Uma solução que tentei até agora foi criar uma chave no registro do windows chamada **ServicesPipeTimeout** esperando que o erro fosse de que o tempo limite de espera pelo inicio do serviço fosse muito pequeno, mas infelizmente não resolveu.

No meu computador e de outros muitos clientes o serviço funciona normalmente, porém em alguns poucos ele apresenta este erro, pode ser algum problema de versão, mas estes clientes não tem nada em comum. Como proceder?

Abraços!

Comment: Debugar serviço é o inferno. Coloque o código que esta usando na inicialização do serviço, bem como a versão do .Net. Inclusive, verifique se ela bate com a versão (e as KB's) instaladas nas máquinas que funcionam.

Comment: Eu verifiquei nas máquinas, mas uma das soluções que eu encontrei foi instalar uma atualização do Visual C++ 1.1 que deveria vir em uma atualização do windows. Mas esse hotfix só é para Windows Server 2008 e o sistema das máquinas é Windows Server 2003 ou Windows Server. Tentei buscar problemas nesses SO's mas não encontro nada por parte da MicroSoft

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema era que nos computadores dos clientes mais recentes, havia instalado a versão 4.5 do .NET Framework, enquanto nos demais clientes a versão instalada era a 4.0.

Minha aplicação estava compilada para o framework 4.5, troquei ele pelo 4.0 Client Profile e recompilei todo o executável, então funcionou.

Comment: Olá, Estou com o mesmo problema, no entanto mudei a minha versão e ainda assim nada :/ Tem alguma idéia do que mais posso tentar?

Comment: O que eu percebi que também pode ser causa desses problemas é uma exceção dentro do sistema. Qualquer tipo de erro dentro do sistema é causa desse problema. O ideal seria você debugar os programas usando a opção de exibir todos os erros do VS.

Answer (score 3):

Caso o erro persista, o melhor a se fazer é tentar debugar o serviço, como indicado pelo @KhaosDoctor.

Quando preciso debugar algo, coloco try catch em todos os lugares e tenho uma classe própria pra adicionar log em um caminho especifico. Nada de especial mas já me ajudou bastante:

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace SystecNFCe.Model
{
public class Logger
{
    public void addLog(string str, bool booForcarDataMaquina = true, bool booGerarLog = true)
    {
        StreamWriter arquivoWS = null;

        Util util = new Util();

        String Path = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"Logs\";
        String Time = "";

        if (!booGerarLog) //se for pra nao gerar log, pular fora da funçao
        {
            return;
        }

        try
        {
            //verifica se existe o diretorio
            if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(Path) == false)
            {
                System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(Path);
            }

            //verifica se existe o arquivo com a data de hoje
            if (arquivoWS == null)
            {
                arquivoWS = new StreamWriter(Path + "SystecNFCe" + DateTime.Now.Date.ToString("yyyy_MM_dd") + ".log", true);
            }

            if (booForcarDataMaquina == false)
            {
                Time = util.GetTimeStampLog();

                if (Time.ToString().Trim() == "")
                {
                    Time = "LOCAL TIME[" + DateTime.Now + "]";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Time = "LOCAL TIME[" + DateTime.Now + "]";
            }

            arquivoWS.WriteLine(Time + " - " + str); //escreve no log (data/hora - o log que queremos) 
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            arquivoWS.Flush();
            arquivoWS.Dispose();
            arquivoWS = null;
            util = null;
        }
    }

}
```

}